# If _id has any special usage in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have one nodejs app, which define answer like this:

```
var answerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    session  : String, // the ID of the session
    question : String, // the ID of the question
    answer   : Number  // the selected answer (1-5)
});
```

stored as answer

```
var sessionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name   : String, // the name of the session, like 'SAM' or 'SA'
    currQ  : Number, // the current question being answered
    state  : String, // the state of the current question: new, done, asking, summarize
    active : Number  // 1 if active, 0 otherwise
});
```

stored as session.

In the ejs file, one function get one answer-tpye variable and use

`var reply = JSON.parse(res);`

then

```
session = reply.session._id;
```

I am really confused what's this line means. There are still many case when _id is used but they didn't define it.

Comment: Are you sure the method that is called is not setting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_id is added to all MongoDB documents by default.

Mongoose also adds an id getter for a string representation of _id so you can also call

```
reply.session.id
```

These properties will be available without being explicitly added to the schema

Comment: What are they meaning here since I didn't define

Comment: when you are using a technology (mongdb) go through the fundamentals of it first. it will help you delivering better outcome.